# Word file input to Hadoop Parser

Tags: hadoop, ms-word

Iam trying to extract data from the word document in Hadoop Parser but the word document content cannot be viewed in the Hparse over the right side but its coming well for the PDFs.How to do and what the steps to parse a word document in Hparser?